# How can i access files from a docker image?

Tags: image, tomcat, docker, containers, camunda

First i just want to mention i am very new to docker.
I am using Win 10, "Docker for Windows".
I am using the default linux containers option.

I have downloaded the latest image from here,

https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform.

So now, my Docker is online, and the container + image are working. A tomcat server and a Camunda engine are online and working.

My problem is the following,

I need to do some changes and i cant find where Tomcat and Camunda are being stored. I need to edit some XML files both in the Camunda and in the Tomcat ( to setup which database to use for example ).

Can it be that it is not being stored on my local machine?

For example when i open the container with Kitematic ( Docker UI ) i can see environment variables for it,  there is a `SERVER_CONFIG` and its value is `/camunda/conf/server.xml`  ( this is one of the files i need to edit! but i cant find it or anything else anywhere on my local machine ).

Comment: You need to create a new image based on the existing image (i.e.`camunda/camunda-bpm-platform`) and copy your custom XML based configurations to the desired directory while creating the new Docker image such as one shown by the `SERVER_CONFIG` so that they can be ready by the environment variables. Moreover, you can configure the database connections in via the environment variables shown in the repository.

Comment: Have you tried `docker exec -i IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash` and navigate to `/camunda` ?

Answer (score 0):

you should access container using following command

1. sudo docker ps -a

```html
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
5e978f353734        camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest   "/sbin/tini -- ./cam…"   4 days ago          Up 4 days
```

2. the issie

sudo docker exec -it 5e978f353734 /bin/bash

3. then you will see the container insie via shell command. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Camunda BPM RUN, which aims to allow configuration without having to change the WAR deployment or Tomcat. Instead configuration is done as described here:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/camunda-bpm-run/

Config files can be mounted into the docker images, but you may prefer to compose your own docker image based on the Camunda BPM Run base image.

The example here shows another approach which sets Camunda properties from outside the docker image by passing the environment variable **SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON** into the docker image.

https://medium.com/@robert.emsbach/anyone-can-run-camunda-bpm-on-azure-in-10-minutes-4b4055cc8e9